# Filter out stored procedures that was changed for the day from sys.procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to get a list of stored procedures that have been created for the current day or has been modified for the current day.

I have the following that works and gets me the results  as follows:

```
SELECT  
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),
    name  as StoredProcedureName, 
    create_date, 
    modify_date 
FROM 
    sys.procedures
WHERE  
    create_date >= '2018-09-12 00:00:00'  OR 
    modify_date >= '2018-09-12 00:00:00'  
ORDER BY 
    modify_date DESC
```

[image: Sample data]

the problem is that im trying to ignore the "SqlQueryNotification" entries. So i want it to get me the results ignoring the above mentioned name.

i tried the following

```
SELECT  
    SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id),
    name  as StoredProcedureName, 
    create_date, 
    modify_date 
FROM 
    sys.procedures
WHERE  
    create_date >= '2018-09-12 00:00:00' OR 
    modify_date >= '2018-09-12 00:00:00' AND 
    name NOT LIKE '%SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedures%'
ORDER BY 
    modify_date DESC
```

but it still gives me the same records as the picture. its not ignoring those records, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Parentheses around the OR clause: `where ( x or y ) and z`

Comment: Should that 's' at the end of your `LIKE` be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `WHERE` conditions to the following:

```
--Want to keep only items that were created on or after 2018-09-12 and do not have a name 
--like 'sqlquerynotification' OR items that were modified on or after 2018-09-12 and do 
--not have a name like 'sqlquerynotification
WHERE  
   (create_date >='2018-09-12 00:00:00' AND 
    name NOT LIKE '%SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedures%') OR
   (modify_date>='2018-09-12 00:00:00' AND 
    name NOT LIKE '%SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedures%')
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You need brackets around the OR criteria
2. You don't need the placeholder in front of `SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure`
3. You must not add a plural "s" after `SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure`

So the query could look like this:

```
SELECT  s.[name] AS SchemaName, p.[name] AS StoredProcedureName, p.create_date, p.modify_date 
FROM sys.procedures p
  INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON p.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE  (p.create_date >= '2018-09-12 00:00:00' OR p.modify_date >= '2018-09-12 00:00:00')
  AND p.[name] NOT LIKE 'SqlQueryNotificationStoredProcedure%'
ORDER BY p.modify_date DESC
```

Comment: Thank you,this helped. Just dont need the inner join

Comment: @George You are right, you can of course use the system function for that, but that will **force** SQL Server to search its system tables for each procedure found, resulting in some kind of a "nested loop join". Using the join in the query, SQL Server can decide on an execution plan that could be more efficient. :-)